# How to judge whether model is overfitting or not

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

I am doing video classification with a model combining CNN and LSTM.
In the training data, the accuracy rate is 100%, but the accuracy rate of the test data is not so good.
The number of training data is small, about 50 per class.
In such a case, can I declare that over learning is occurring?
Or is there another cause?

Comment: why you are running the model of training data? instead create a validation data from train dataset. And your dataset very small, try to get more data.

Comment: Wrong site, got to http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yes, you are :)

Comment: I'm sorry I will go to that site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you are indeed overfitting if the performance of your model is perfect on the training data, yet poor on test/validation data set.

A good way of observing that effect is to evaluate your model on both training and validation data after each epoch of training. You might observe that while you train, the performance on your validation set is increasing initially, and then starts to decrease. That is the moment when your model starts to overfit and where you can interrupt your training.

Here's a plot demonstrating this phenomenon with the blue and red lines corresponding to errors on training and validation sets respectively. 
[image]